# laravel where on relationship table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel, I have a main table with 'projects' and a table with 'users', an intermediate table linking the two as a many-to-many relationship.

Now I want to display a list of projects, but if they are over 'projects.max_people' then they should be hidden from this list, how do I do this in laravel?

The problem is im 'get()'ing the users in the view, after I did Project::get()... how do I add this where condition?

Comment: we are also helpless! where is your model's code? table design? without any info, how can we help you?

Comment: i was moreover hoping for a general solution, I will edit it first thing

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new object called ProjectUser or so. In this object should contain a 'project_id' and 'user_id'.

Then, your Project model would look something like this:

```
<?php

class Project extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'projects';

    public function projectUsers(){
       $this->hasMany('ProjectUser', 'project_id');
    }
}
```

The User class:

```
<?php

class Project extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'projects';

    public function projectUsers(){
       $this->hasMany('ProjectUser', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

The ProjectUser class:

```
class ProjectUser extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'project_users';

    public function project(){
       $this->belongsTo('Project'`enter code here`, 'project_id');
    }

    public function user(){
       $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Now, you can get the users of a project like so:

```
$projects = Project::with('projectUsers.user')->get();
```

When looping through these objects you can access the user like this:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)

   @foreach($project->projectUsers as $projectUser)

      {{ $projectUser->user->id }}

   @endforeach

@endforeach
```